# How do I make the input text field take all available width?

Tags: html, css, width, margin

I am trying to stretch an input text field to the available width (minus margins). This does not work. Why?

```
  <div style="background:yellow; padding:5px;">
    <input id="test-input" type="text" />
  </div>
  <style type="text/css">
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    #test-input {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        border: 1px black solid;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: `box-sizing`: FYI you still need prefix for Firefox (and WebKit to a lesser degree) [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Comment: If you need a solution compatible with IE8- and Android 4.3-, have a larger padding on parent and `width: 100%` on input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS3 [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to calculate the `width` excluding the left/right margins, as follows:

```css
#test-input {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px); /* Exclude left/right margins */
    display: block;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aA8B5/)**

Or use `padding` for the container instead of using `margin` for the input:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input id="test-input" type="text" />
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#test-input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aA8B5/2/)**

Comment: Hey I just learned something from your answer i had no idea you could use calc. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks @Hashem. I have never seen CSS calc before. "Padding" also works, but it seems a bit strange you have to remove "margin" to avoid overflow. I thought box-sizing:border-box should take care of that.

Comment: You might want to note that `calc()` is experimental and doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @j08691 Exactly, I added a link to the MDN page for further reading.

Comment: @Leo Don't mention it :)